# Regex to match forward slash surrounded by double quotes

Tags: regex

I have a serialised string that comes from Spring hosted end-points. On the frontend which is javascript based, I wanted to prettify the serialised string that comes from API to a string that is parsable through JSON.parse();

Please let me know the regex to match and replace the required fields as below.

sample string: `\"address\":\"<VALUE>"\"},` I want to replace all the instances of `"\"` which comes at the end of VALUE with `\"`

Tried doing this: `str.replaceAll('\"/\\\"', '/\\\"')` but no luck.

Comment: If your string is something like: `"{ \"age:\" : 20, \"name:\": \"jhon\" }"` then there is no need to prettify it since it is parse-able as it is. If it's not add some examples of your input.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, we have to escape characters to put the wanted values into the variable:

```js
testString='\\\"address\\\":\\\"<VALUE>"\\\"},';
alert(testString);
alert(testString.replace(/\"\\\"/,'\\\"'));
```

The first alert gives us the originale testString:

```
\"address\":\"<VALUE>"\"},
```

and the second the modified testString

```
\"address\":\"<VALUE>\"},
```

Tested with https://www.webtoolkitonline.com/javascript-tester.html